# Using Objective-c (ios) how to assign a value for the key pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

Using Objective-C (ios programming), I would like to get user's input and assign value to each
input.  For example, if the user presses "A" or "a" or "B", or "b", I would like to assign a number value 1. Similarly I need to assign a numeric value for each key.  Some times the same value can be assigned to different letters like the above example.

What is the best way to implement this.  Pl provide an example.  I was thinking to use enum or key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a dictionary to store the map relation and fetch the corresponding number by the string key that user has input.

```
self.charMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<26; ++i) {
    [self.charMap setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1] forKey:[upperCaseChars substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
    [self.charMap setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1] forKey:[lowerCaseChars substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
}

// Example of use
NSString *userInput = @"b";
NSNumber *correspondingNumber = [self.charMap objectForKey:userInput];
```